# Программа ничего не выводит и не возвращает (циклы)

Tags: c++, while

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a[5][5];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        while(j<4)
        {
            if(j-i >= 0)
            {
                a[i][j] = '1';
                j++;
            }
            else a[i][j] = ' ';
               j++;
        }
        j = 0;
    }
    j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        while(j<4)
        {
            cout << a[i][j];
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Код ничего не выводит и не возвращает, подозреваю что застревает в цикле, но не могу найти где.

Comment: У вас не болят глаза смотреть на такое форматирование? И почему вы не пользуетесь отладчиком?

Comment: clion ошибок не выдает.

Comment: Отладчиком, а не компилятором.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скажите, что будет в первом же цикле `while` при второй итерации, когда `i=1`, а `j` равно 0?

Все понятно? :)

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек, воистину глупая ошибка :)